# Loop in Parents error even move mesh and rig to world origin

Tags: rigging

I want to parent the bones to the mesh so I can move the mesh the way I want. I 1st went to object mode and select the mesh and then shift select  the rig, and then I click on parent, then armature deform, then with automatical weight, but then I got parent in loop error. Some people say it's because the mesh and rig are not symatrical.But here is the problem:
I've moved mesh and rig to world orgin, and the rig I use is the human meta rig. I tried to scale the rig bigger to fit in the mesh, but somehow the mesh and the rig are still not symatrical. Is it because the mesh is just not symatrical? or what's wrong with my steps?

Comment: Before you do any parenting, try selecting the armature (in Object mode) and press CTL-A --> "Scale".  Do the same with the model.  That will reset their respective scale value back to 1. If you've rotated the armature before parenting, that might also require a CTL-A --> "Rotation".

Comment: still says loop..

Comment: Try a new temporary project.  Two cubes, one on top of the other.  Rig those without Auto Weights to begin with.  Just parent each cube (in pose mode) to it's own bone. If no errors try the rig out, rotate each bone.  If all ok, do the 'Inverse Kinetics' step, and apply auto weights. Test that out.  If that's ok you know the original project has been rigged differently and possibly needs a redo.  Once you clear that of object/bones constraints (inverse kinetics etc), Save it and exit to clear any 'ghosts' that can linger in buffers etc.
Reload and re-run, confirm it's virgin again.

Comment: I'll look back in again in an hour...

Comment: Ok, I tried over do the mesh and rig again and this time there is no loop error but when I parent them, by weight, the mesh became so big! I don't know what happend! How can I parent them just normally??

Comment: Are you running 2.8x?  I'm on 2.77a here. If you're on 2.8+ I don't think I can load your Blend file, but you may be able to load mine. Whatsay I do what you've done and send you the Blend file to see if it works properly in your version?

Comment: 2.81, But I scaled the mesh back after, it's ok now.

Comment: You got it sorted, that's good! :)